# How to run 'Flutter Flame engine' tutorial example?

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to learn flutter.

is this([link](https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/)) only for web??

can i run this in android studio??

1. I did "git clone" https://github.com/flame-engine/flame, in my folder.
2. Open project at android studio. (already set up, flutter, flame engine)
   [main.dart is doesn't work, also Flame(Folder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKv4b.png)
3. main.dart is not working
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1hYo.png)

but, trex is exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MEZI.png)

4. 'run packages/flame' is also doesn't
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoSTI.png)

++++++

pubspeck.yaml
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1bt6.png)

i did pub get, upgrade.

Comment: Can you edit your question including the contents of your *pubspec.yaml* file?

Comment: but, I think it is not problem of pubspec.yaml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow our [contribution doc](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#environment-setup) for how to set up the environment first.

Basically what you have to do is:

1. Install Melos: `flutter pub global activate melos 3.0.0-dev.0`
2. Run `melos bootstrap`
3. Now you should be able to run the `main.dart` file in the `examples` directory from your IDE or from the terminal.